# File download in REST uing jersey and RESTclient in firefox not showing download pop up

Tags: rest, popup, jersey, download

I'm writing a code to download files using ReST API. my code is working fine and I am getting a response back.
But  i am getting the file content as  response body in browser rather than asking for a file download

below is the sample code I am using.. please help me to figure out what i am doing wrong.
I tried all the codes posted in SO that matched with my requirement but still i could not get the pop up .

```java
@Path("/downloadfiles")
public class DownloadFiles {

    @GET

    @Produces("text/plain")
    public Response getFiles( ) {

        File file = new File("/opt/test/sample.csv");
        ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file).header("Content-Disposition",
                 "attachment; filename=sample.csv");

        return response.build();

    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hello try to make it produce "application/octet-stream" instead of text/plain

The kind of content you specify is the reason you only see text

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried that too i am getting the same response

Answer (score 0):

Try @Produces("test/csv") and if that alone doesn't work try also setting the entity on the ResponseBuilder to the String contents of your file. That works for me, anyway.

BTW, in my browser I don't get a popup, it just starts downloading the CSV file immediately.